# Axios Vue: undefined post parameters in express server but defined in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express

I have an `<img>` element like this:

```html
<img v-bind:word = "thing" @click="action" align="center" src="../assets/pic.png"/>
```

and a method like this:

```js
 async action() {
      let imgAttribute = event.target.getAttribute('word');
      alert(imgAttribute ); // alerts OK
      console.log("imgAttribute : " + imgAttribute ); // prints OK

     await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/my/endpoint',
         {
           params: {
             word: imgAttribute 
           }
         });
...
```

So when the `<img>` element is clicked, the method `action` is executed. The `word` attribute is taken and put in `imgAttribute` variable, which is then passed as a parameter in the post request.

`alert(imgAttribute)` and `console.log(imgAttribute)` work fine, which means they don't print `undefined`, but print correct string values that are inside `word` attribute.

However on Express server:

```js
app.post('/my/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
    const {word} = req.params;  // tried req.query with the same (undefined) result
    console.log("word = " + word); // undefined
...
```

The `word` is undefined.

Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed as body via .post, to pass as params use

```
  await axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/my/endpoint',
    method: 'post',
    params: {
        word: imgAttribute 
    }
  })
```